# Actionscript 3: Access movieclips from array with for-loop

Tags: actionscript-3, class, for-loop, instance

I am having some trouble with accessing the movieclips I've added as childs. From what I've read, a way to solve this is to add every new movieclip to an array, and then loop through this array when I want to change something about all the movieclips.

In my case I want to scale them.

This is how I've tried to implement this function:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import Airport;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public var tile:MovieClip

    public var bg_image:Sprite;
    public var airport:Airport;

    public static var airportDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public static var collectedAirportArray:Array = new Array();


    public function Main()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    public function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

                    // airportDict is being filled up here.. but that's not really relevant for my problem

        bg_image = new Image();
        addChild(bg_image);

        bg_image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testfunction);

        for (var k:Object in airportDict)
        {
            var airport:Airport = new Airport(k,airportDict[k]["x"], airportDict[k]["y"]);
            collectedAirportArray.push(collectedAirportArray);
            bg_image.addChild(airport);
        }
    }

    private function testfunction(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        for each (tile in collectedAirportArray)
        {
            tile.scaleY = 2 * tile.scaleY;
        }
    }

}
```

}

This give me the error message `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@30977eb1 to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at Main/testfunction()` when clicking on the `bg_image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in where you are making the array. You have there `collectedAirportArray.push(collectedAirportArray);` - you're basically pushing an array into itself. Nice snakey, they said. You should instead push the newly created airport in there:

```
collectedAirportArray.push(airport);
```

If your `airport` is any kind of `DisplayObject` your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

What `AirPort` class is extending? If it extends `MovieClip` then try type casting like so:

```
private function testfunction(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    for each (tile in collectedAirportArray)
    {
       var myTile:MovieClip = MovieClip(tile); 
       myTile.scaleY = 2 * myTile.scaleY;
    }
}
```